# Runserver at django some problems

Tags: python, django

PS C:\Users\Manthan Sharma\PycharmProjects\Django> python manage.py runserver

[image: 1]

```
C:\Users\Manthan Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\Manthan Sharma\PycharmProjects\Django>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Run the below steps:**

```
cd mysite/mysite
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

your project is inside `mysite` folder, so does your `manage.py`.

you need to run the command, inside the folder where your `manage.py` is, like this

```
C:\Users\Manthan Sharma\PycharmProjects\Django\mysite> python manage.py runserver
```